# Starting a question with "Dare I"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage

For question sentences that start with "Dare I" like "Dare I join them?" can it mean: Should I take the risk of joining them? Or does it strictly mean: Do I have the bravery to join them?

It would mean the latter, according to definitions I've seen of the word "dare" but I've always thought that it could mean the former. Please confirm that I've been mistaken.

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence that you think *dare* works in, but you don't think is covered by the dictionary definitions? Your question, as stated, is currently a little too vague.

Comment: Since *bravery* might almost be defined as willingness to take risks, I wonder what difference you are seeing between these two meanings.

Comment: Apart from dares between children I can only think of the context "Dare I ***say*** that ..."